# Java How to make a socket connection secure?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography

I want to setup a secure socket connection between a Server and a Client.
My protocol is:

1. The Client generates a RSA keypair and send it's public key to the server.
2. The Server generates a AES key, encypts the key with the client's public key and ends it to the client.
3. The client decrypts the AES key with the private key.
4. All messages are encrypted and decrypted with the AES key.

The problem:
This protocol is very vulnerable against Man-in-the-middle attacks. A attacker could easily send his own public key to the server, and receive the AES key. The attacker can spoof to be the server to the client and to be the client to the server. 
How to make my connection secure?

Comment: Use TLS with publicly-signed certificates, unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: I have no idea what this is... Can you please explain this solution bit.

Comment: Then please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security before coming up with your own protocol.

Comment: This article say I need a certificate? What is this and how to get one?

Comment: And how to implement all this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marc says, use TLS. TLS uses [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to secure the connection between A and B. This is also what makes HTTPS secure.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm#JSSEC-GUID-A4D59ABB-62AF-4FC0-900E-A795FDC84E41) a short example in Java. Note that the term SSL is used - TLS used to be SSL, but the term is still used interchangeably.

Comment: This article say I need a certificate? How to get one?

Comment: I'd like to generate my own certificates, so I don't have to relay on the JDK

Comment: Also this article describes a HTTPS connection, I need a socket connection without HTTP.

Comment: That's great, you should. What you're looking for is a self-signed certificate. Try [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self). Creating a certificate is relatively easy. You then need to load the certificate into a [Java truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html). Try following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/hakky54mutual-tls-1) step by step guide if you're having trouble.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Diffie-Hellman does **not** make TLS secure against the man-in-the-middle (MITM). It is the authentication framework of TLS that makes it secure (or not) against MITM. For the internet, this means the system of certificate authorities whose keys are more or less hard-coded in TLS clients. This CA model is not perfect and there have been documented exploits. Weakness in this model translate directly to weaknesses in TLS against MITM.

Comment: Other authentication models are possible, including self-signed certificates. Every such model has it pros and cons, its strengths and weakness, both in terms of security and user-friendliness. Making every customer/user/TLS client install your self-signed cert is very user-unfriendly. Hard-coding it in your software is more user-friendly but carries its own set of difficulties, and moves the trust point to trusting the channel you received the software from. I believe the CA model represents the best choice for 99.9% of TLS scenarios.